как при открытии песни открыть ссылку
Допустим у меня есть песня локально, не в браузере, я ее запускаю и хочу чтобы при открытии меня перенаправило в браузер на нужное мне окно. как это сделать?

У элемента audio есть событие onplay(), которое перехватывает воспроизведение, вот оно и может перенаправить на другую страницу:


<audio src="1.mp3" onplay="location.href='http://site.com'" controls></audio>



Но дело в том, что песня так и не начнёт играть, вместо музыки будет перенаправление. Обойти эту ситуацию может открытие ссылки в новой вкладке браузера:


<a id=a href="http://mysite.com" target="_blank">Ссылка</a>
<audio src="1.mp3" onplay="a.click()" controls></audio>



Или так:


<audio src="1.mp3" onplay="window.open('http://mysite.com')" controls></audio>



Если речь шла о том, чтобы просто открыть на компьютере песню, (допустим, двойным кликом) следует задекларировать браузер, как программу по умолчанию для открытия аудиофайлов, а в настройках браузера нужную страницу задать, как страницу по умолчанию после открытия браузера.

спасибо за ответ. речь шла об том что другой человек скачав мой трек, например торрентом, у себя на компьютере его откроет и его перенаправит на страницу... у себя я то сделаю браузером по умолчанию открытие аудио и все будет ок,это понятно,  но будет ли это работать у других?

Не будет, пока они не сделают у себя то же самое.
